# How to update Composer in Windows 10

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using Composer for my PHP project. I am new to Composer. Now when I update my dependencies using `composer update` command, it is saying that my Composer version is too old and ask me to update. So I tried as below. But all failed.

My `composer.phar` file is in `C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar`

I opened terminal and tried

```
composer.phar update

php composer.phar update

composer C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar update

php composer C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar update
```

When I run `composer-self-update`, error as in screenshot.

[image]

All command failed. I am using XAMPP. There is no `composer.phar` file in `xampp/php` folder as well. How can I update Composer in Windows 10?

Comment: seems like your  dns can't resolve getcomposer.org try updating your dns to 8.8.8.8, that might help

Comment: I tried compiser self-update 3 times. It is not working. But I closed terminal. Then do other works. After few minutes, I run "composer self-update" again. Now it is working. Why? I did not do any changes. :o

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36786908/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Try

```
composer self-update
```

If this doesn't work, check your PATH variable. If it's not there, try searching file *composer.bat* in Windows and add it to your PATH variable. Normally, it’s in the following path.

> C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

Comment: He is talking about updating composer program, not the project dependencies.

Comment: oops i did meant self-update(look at the comment) but wrote composer update.

Comment: Hmm.. that was you in the comment.

Comment: You mean I have to add it to PATH the is under System variables of environment variables?

Comment: no, try updating your dns to 8.8.8.8, that might help

Comment: didn't you say its working now? no need to update your dns.

Comment: Yes working. But I did not know why. Just working and updated. In first 3 times throwing errors like in my screenshot.

Comment: This is still working end of 2020, I did: $ composer self-update from Windows 10 (MINGW64) today; version 1.9.1 to 1.10.15 and notifies me of a rollback option if needed with: $ composer self-update --rollback

Comment: Command "self-update" is not defined.  @rishal

Comment: it worked for me. Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 21):

**Windows 10 update for Composer still works (end of 2020, pre version 2) with:**

Follow this below image:

[image]

`composer self-update --1` **it will be updated from 1.x**

`composer self-update --2` **it will be updated from 2.x and from 1.x**

`composer self-update --rollback`  **If you need to roll back to your previous version**

**`composer -V` For check your composer version**

**composer self-update:**

If you run `composer self-update` from 1.x, it will warn you that a new stable major version of Composer is available, and you can use `composer self-update --2` to migrate to it.

**So run `composer self-update --2`**

**How easy is it to upgrade?**

- Composer 2.0 still supports PHP 5.3 and above, much like Composer 1.x
- *composer.lock* files are interoperable between versions, so you can
  upgrade to 2.0 and roll back easily if needed.
- Most commands and arguments remain the same, and largely what you
  know about Composer remains true in 2.0.

Comment: Use composer -V and not composer -v to check version.

Answer (score 15):

Windows 10 update for Composer still works (end of 2020, pre version 2) with:

```
composer self-update
```

If you need to rollback to your previous version, you can do that with:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Comment: Works in Windows 11 too.

Answer (score 5):

Try.

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

'update' updates your dependencies, not Composer itself.

Comment: when you type php compser.phar what happens?

Comment: It just open up the composer.phar file in notepad.

Comment: Tell you what.. goto https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe
Download the composer windows installer.. Installing it from there will install it globally for you.. then you will only have to 'composer' from anywhere and it will be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
composer self-update --2
```

By default, the installer and `composer self-update` will download the latest stable version only. To programmatically install specific major versions you can use the `--1` or `--2` flag.

To go back to the previous version:

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

To check the current version

```
composer --version
```